# How to make javascript file update take effect immediately on IIS for asp.net web sites?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, caching, iis, config

I'm writing an asp.net project. When trying to fix a bug, I updated one of my javascript files and then deployed the new version on my server's IIS 6.0. I can see that the new javascript file has been updated on the physical folder of the website.
  However, when verifying the bug from my local machine I found that it's not fixed. After some investigation, I realized that it's because the javascript file received by my browser is not the latest version.
  I deleted IE's caches and the problem still exists. Then I tried to download the javascript directly from my website by using the url like: 
    http://myserver.mydomain.com/mywebsite/scripts/myscript.js 
and found out the downloaded javascript file is of the old version. 
  Then I realized this is probably caused by a cache on the server side. I tried to set the server's IIS: on my site's "Output Caching" option, I unchecked "Enable cache" and "Enable kernel cache"

:[image]

Also I added rules for .js and .css file:
[image]

After taking all these actions, I updated my javascript file on the server, restarted IIS and tried to download it from my local machine again.However, the javascript I downloaded is still not the latest version.

So my question is, **what shall I do to make sure the the browser can *immediately* get the latest version of the javascript file on my server's disk**? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the old trick of **js and css versioning**, for example if I create a new js file I call:

```
new_1.0.0.js
```

Then, if for some reason I change, I will change the name manually to:

```
new_1.0.1.js
```

Also change **all the parts where I Referencing**. With this, your browser should always bring you the latest standalone version of the settings you have in the IIS. At least in my different jobs where I used II6 or II7 have applied and it has worked.

Comment: Simple, but so obvious. Thanks for the idea !

Comment: It's crazy to me that there is no better solution for this. Been googling and trying various things to no avail. I've got about 30+ changed js files. Do i really need to go in and manually rename all of them and change all the references? That seems insane.

Comment: In C#, exists other trick using autogenerated JS renamed post compilation configuration. It using web.config section.